# Passing NSTextField Pointer to IOUSBInterfaceInterface182 Callback

Tags: cocoa, callback, usb

I'm doing an asynchronous read from a USB printer.  The read works correctly.  My trouble is updating a NSTextField from within the callback.

```
-(IBAction)printTest:(id)sender
{
    // Setup... then:

    NSLog(@"starting async read: %@", _printerOutput);
    NSLog(@"_printerOutput pointer = %p", _printerOutput);

    result = (*interface)->ReadPipeAsyncTO(interface,
                                           1,
                                           readBuffer,
                                           numBytesRead,
                                           500,
                                           1000,
                                           USBDeviceReadCompletionCallback,
                                           &(_printerOutput)
                                           );
```

The callback is defined as:

```
void USBDeviceReadCompletionCallback(void *refCon, IOReturn result, void *messageArg)
{
    NSTextField *printerOutput = (__bridge NSTextField *) messageArg;
    NSLog(@"_printerOutput pointer = %p", printerOutput);
}
```

The pointer loses its value when inside of the callback.

```
starting async read: <NSTextField: 0x10221dc60>
_printerOutput pointer = 0x10221dc60
_printerOutput pointer = 0x0
```

I've looked in many places trying to mimic different ways to pass in the pointer.  There can be only one correct way.  :)

Another variation on the theme:  (__bridge void *)(_printerOutput).  This doesn't work, either.

I understand that the callback is of type IOAsyncCallback1.

Other URLs of note:
    http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=another+usb+notification+example&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8 and  [updating UI from a C function in a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010382/updating-ui-from-a-c-function-in-a-thread)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume `_printerOutput` is an `NSTextField*`?

First, is there a particular reason why are you passing an `NSTextField**` into the callback? (Note the ampersand in the last argument you're passing to `ReadPipeAsyncTO`.)

Second, I'd avoid ARC with sensitive code, just as a precaution.

Third, [from what I see](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOUSBInterfaceInterface182_reference/translated_content/IOUSBInterfaceInterface182.html), last argument of `ReadPipeAsyncTO` is called `refcon`. Is it a coincidence that callback's first argument is called `refCon`? Note you're trying to get a text field from `messageArg`, not `refCon`.

---

To extend on my third point…

1. `ReadPipeAsyncTO` has an argument called `refcon`. This is the **last argument**.
2. Please pass `_printerOutput` there. Not a pointer to `_printerOutput` (do not pass `&(_printerOutput)`) -- `_printerOutput` is already a pointer.
3. **Now finally.** Look at the first argument of the callback. It's called `refcon`. In fact -- let's see what [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOKitLib_header_reference/Reference/reference.html) say about this callback:

> *refcon*
>
> The refcon passed into the original I/O request

My conclusion is that your code should read:

```
void USBDeviceReadCompletionCallback(void *refCon, IOReturn result, void *messageArg)
{
    NSTextField *printerOutput = (__bridge NSTextField *) refCon; // <=== the change is here
    NSLog(@"_printerOutput pointer = %p", printerOutput);
}
```

Can you, please, try this out? I get a feeling that you didn't try this.

Small but possibly important digression: Were it some other object, and if you didn't use ARC, I'd suggest retaining the `_printerOutput` variable when passing it into `ReadPipeAsyncTO`, and releasing it in the callback.

But, since the text field should, presumably, have the lifetime of the application, there is probably no need to do so.

ARC probably loses track of the need for the object behind the pointer to exist once it's passed into C code, but it doesn't matter, since the pointer is still stored in the `printerOutput` property. Besides, once a pointer is in C code, nothing can just "follow it around" and "reset it".

Confusion when it comes to understanding and explaining the concepts is precisely why I said "avoid ARC with sensitive code". :-)

Comment: Yes, _printerOutput is the NSTextField object defined as @property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextField *printerOutput;  It's safe to say my code is based on guessing at this point.  The first argument of IOAsyncCallback1 is the original refCon, which in this case is the variable interface.

Comment: IOAsyncCallback1 is documented at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOKitLib_header_reference/Reference/reference.html

Comment: There is also this thread, but this code still causes the pointer to become valueless.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916491/pass-an-objective-c-object-to-a-function-as-a-void-pointer

Comment: @CaylanVanLarson I'm also trying to be clairvoyant here, because I never dealt with `IOKit` in detail (at least not on this level, and not with printers). But I get the feeling that you didn't try looking at the value of `refcon` argument that the callback received. See my edit.

Comment: You were right, refCon in the callback is the argument _printerOutput.  Very nice.  Thank you, Ivan.